# Change focus/hint color on Xamarin Forms controls

Tags: xamarin.forms, material-design

I'm creating a default Xamarin Forms app. It is targeting both iOS and Android. When running it on Android (Samsung Galaxy S20), an Picker field gets a colored underline when it is focused. In my case, on my phone, it is magenta. Same thing with the Entry textfield, where the cursor and underline is magenta.

**My question:** Can I change the focused/hint color across the board somehow? Or do I need to go all the way and build a custom theme (inherit from Material design for example), build custom renderers for all controls?

**Note:** I don't use any theme or Material design today. It is a plain vanilla Xamarin Forms app.

Instead of using the color I see now, I would like to replace it with our brand color. And I'm *hoping* (cross my fingers) that I can set a property somehow to get this 'global' color changed.

Or if that isn't possible, is there a middle-way, sort of, where I don't have to build a custom theme with renderers for all controls?

Thanks in advance, Henrik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Android

Inside your android project `YourProjectName.Droid`

There should be `Resources` folder, Inside that `values` folder.

And in that there will be a file `styles.xml`

Inside it

```
<item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
```

Above line is responsible for your magenta color. Change it to your liking.

Comment: Thank you, I'm glad it can be fixed that easily.